# Android material design textinputlayout

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

Is there any way to handle suffix onclick event in android material input ?
I have xml layout like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
        <data>
    
        </data>
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/change_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:suffixText="verify">
    
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="email" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

I want to send to server request, when user click on verify text how I can release this case ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    inputLayout.suffixTextView.setOnClickListener {
        //do something..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help as if you are trying to  handle on press on end icon.

```
textField.setEndIconOnClickListener {
  // Respond to end icon presses}

textField.addOnEditTextAttachedListener {
  // If any specific changes should be done when the     edit text is attached (and
  // thus when the trailing icon is added to it), set  an
  // OnEditTextAttachedListener.

  // Example: The clear text icon's visibility behavior depends on whether the
  // EditText has input present. Therefore, an OnEditTextAttachedListener is set
  // so things like editText.getText() can be called.
}

textField.addOnEndIconChangedListener {
  // If any specific changes should be done if/when the endIconMode gets
  // changed, set an OnEndIconChangedListener.

  // Example: If the password toggle icon is set and a different EndIconMode
  // gets set, the TextInputLayout has to make sure that the edit text's
  // TransformationMethod is still PasswordTransformationMethod. Because of
  // that, an OnEndIconChangedListener is used.
}
```

Incase you need the link to official docs [here you go](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjwjo-cntDwAhVZilwKHVuNDqoQFjAAegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaterial.io%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-fields%2Fandroid&usg=AOvVaw1yMREdxoxKapLesndfDxB0)

Comment: `You question needs more explanation.` if that's how you feel, you should probably comment before attempting an answer, personally i feel this question makes sense